# How to convert millisecond string to datetime in Big Query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We need to convert string to datetime. String format is 'yyyymmddhhmiss.sss', like '20230707005438624'.

Now I'm trying `PARSE_DATETIME` but it does not work well with millisecond parts.

```
select timestamp, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y%m%d%H%M%E*SZ', timestamp)
```

This is not working and throws this error:

> Mismatch between format character 'Z' and string character '4'

```
select timestamp, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', substring(timestamp,1,14))
```

This is working fine, and returns value ex. 20230705020422431, 2023-07-05T02:04:22

Is there any appropriate solution, please advise me.

Thank you.

**Additional Information** :
For someone who closed my question, actually your suggestion, '%Y%m%d%H%M%E*SZ' is not working correctly, as I've already described in my question, so I asked this question.

Oleg's answer worked correctly in my case.
Please DON'T CLOSE the other one's serious question by your own judgement, I'm fullious about it, it's really, really rude.

**Conclusion :**
Finally, I converted by PARSE_TIMESTAMP with Oleg's briliant idea as below.

```
select timestamp, 
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d%H%M%E*S',
    CONCAT(
      SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, 14),
      '.',
      SUBSTR(timestamp, 15, 3)
  )) as converted_timestamp
    from original_table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the milliseconds mask assumes there is a dot separator between seconds and milliseconds part. The workaround is to insert the dot into the timestamp string.

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  select '20230707005438111' as timestamp
)
select timestamp, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y%m%d%H%M%E*S',
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, 14),
    '.',
    SUBSTR(timestamp, 15, 3)
  )
)
from sample_data
```